# Error in Hibernate Mapping "A Foreign key refering has the wrong number of column. should be 2"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping, spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key

`TRANSFORMATION` table having a composite primary key `trans_id` and `version`.
`EXPRESSION` table having foreign key reference from `trans_id` only, it doesn't have a `version` column.

Through JUnit when I try to save into `TRANSFORMATION`,  I am getting below error.

```
caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering org.persistence.entity.Transformation from org.persistence.entity.Expression has the wrong number of column. should be 2
            at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1560) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1481) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
            ...
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250) ~[spring-test-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64) ~[spring-test-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-test-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
            ... 25 more
```

---

```
@Entity(name="Transformation")
@Table(name="Transformation")
public class Transformation extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId 
    private TransformationPK id;
          /*@OneToMany(mappedBy="transformation")
    private Set<Expression> expressions;*/

          @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="TRANS_ID", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Set<Expression> expressions;
}

@Embeddable
public class TransformationPK implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="TRANS_ID")
    private String transId;

    @Column(name="VERSION", precision = 2, scale = 1)
    private Double transVersion;

    public TransformationPK() {
    }
}


@Entity(name="EXPRESSION")
@Table(name="EXPRESSION")
public class Expression extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Expression_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String expressionId;

    @Column(name="TRANS_ID")
    private String transId;

    /*@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns ({
           @JoinColumn(name = "TRANS_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
           @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
          })
    private Transformation transformation;*/

    @ManyToOne
          @JoinColumn(name = "TRANS_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Transformation transformation;
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: you cannot have manyToOne relationship to composite-key parent entity without having all it's PK columns in FK

Answer (score 4):

As your embedded PK has two columns, here you should have two joining columns as well:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({  
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANS_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name = "VERSION", ....
})
private Transformation transformation;
```

BTW, you have bidirectional association Transformation-Expression, you should add mappedBy at one end.

Comment: So Can I add mappedBy in Transaformation Class with  @OneToMany Set<Expression> expressions ?

Comment: I read about @associationoverride in javax.persistence api. Can I use this to solve this issue ?